# need to display an image at the very bottom of a div

Tags: html, css

I want the image to display at the very bottom of the div, the div doesn't have a set height, as it changes based on how much content is in the content-body div

```
<a href="http://facebook.com/page" id="find-us-on-facebook">facebook</a>
```

Here is the css for the link w/ the background-image

```
#featured-left a#find-us-on-facebook:link,
#featured-left a#find-us-on-facebook:visited {
 display: block;
 width: 183px;
 height: 52px;
 text-decoration: none;
 background: url('/images/uploads/images/find-us-on-facebook.png') no-repeat;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-indent: -10000px;
 font-size: 0px;
 line-height: 0px;
}

#featured-left a#find-us-on-facebook:hover {
 background-position: 0 -52px;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-indent: -10000px;
 font-size: 0px;
 line-height: 0px;
}
```

Comment: which image? background image?  or some different image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `padding-bottom: 52px` to the content div in which your facebook button is located equal to the height of the button (52px) (if there is already some padding at the bottom of the container add it to 52px or add even more to create a gap between the button and the content) and set position property of content div to `position: relative`.

Then set your facebook button position to `position: absolute` and position it with `bottom: 0` and whatever `left`, or `right` you see fit.

Then there is one more and a bit more civil solution - to simply put it at the very bottom of the content you put inside the content div. Although I assume that since you ask about this you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean your background image and that you still want it left aligned (as it would be by default) change

```
background: url('/images/uploads/images/find-us-on-facebook.png') no-repeat
```

to

```
background: url('/images/uploads/images/find-us-on-facebook.png') no-repeat left bottom
```

Comment: Did it change the position of the image at all? Also, did you check to make sure that another style isn't interfering?

Comment: Or the background image is the same height as the container

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
vertical-align:bottom;
```

That might work.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the following CSS:

```
#featured-left {
 position: relative;
}

#featured-left a#find-us-on-facebook {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

and make sure that the div that you want this to be displayed in at the very bottom doesn't have `position: static`

I hope this is what you're looking for.